# Hide LaTeX parts through JavaScript

Tags: hyperref, javascript

I'm creating an interactive pdf form with the `hyperref` package. The form is quite comprehensive, so the current goal is to only show parts that are relevant to the specific user. For example, the user indicates that he is male --> only the items that concern males are displayed.

Usually it's not difficult to display only certain parts of a document, e.g. using the  `ifthen` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
    \newboolean{boolvar}
    \setboolean{boolvar}{false}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{boolvar}}{show if true}{show if false}
\end{document}
```

I'm lost, however, when it comes to combining variables like that with user input from form fields. Using JavaScript and the `insdljs` package, I've gotten as far as hiding form fields, but not text outside of these form fields: (Note: `insdljs` is not part of TeX Live, but available [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

\begin{insDLJS}{mydljs}{some comment}
    function hide(){
         if(this.getField("somefield").display == display.visible){
             this.getField("somefield").display = display.hidden;
         } else{
             this.getField("somefield").display = display.visible;
         }
    }
\end{insDLJS}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \PushButton[onclick={hide();}]{Hide/Show}\\
        \TextField[name=somefield, width=4em]{Any way to hide e.g. this text?}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Hiding form fields like that is very handy, but I'd like to apply that to entire tables or sections. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I can't help but I'm probably not the only person who would love to see whatever you come up with!

Comment: @LostBrit Thanks, but what I've been able to dig up so far seems quite disheartening. For example, in a related post the accepted answer read _If you want parts of the PDF to change based on form events, you pretty much have to make those changing things read-only text fields._ The topic wasn't exactly the same, though. So there is still some hope!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know actually, but I conducted small research, and think that you can't hide it, you can do nothing with it, at all (without a little trick, of course)

First of all, I create a simple example and open it in Adobe Acrobat. I see, that a field and a label independent. And there is no any TextField properties that can change the label. Textfield it's field, label it's text.

[image]

If you really wanna hide label, you can do something like this:

[image]

1. you hide field 'test', and 'tf1' is visible
2. field 'test' is visible, 'tf1' to hide

It works, but I don't sure, that you need it.

In order to verify that we can't change the text, I have played with the buttons. Using [javascript API for Acrobat Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) I found `buttonGetCaption` and `buttonSetCaption` methods, to change label (seems like caption), it works not as I expected:

```
\PushButton[name=testButton1,onclick={
console.show();
console.println('-------------');
console.println('value is: '    +event.target.value);
console.println('caption is: '  +event.target.buttonGetCaption());
console.println('-------------');
event.target.buttonGetCaption()==''?event.target.buttonSetCaption('boom'):event.target.buttonSetCaption('');
}]{\ test\ }
\PushButton[name=testButton2,onclick={
event.target.buttonGetCaption()==''?event.target.buttonSetCaption('boom'):event.target.buttonSetCaption('');
}]{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ }\\[0.2cm] %I didn't find as to change width. Parameter 'width' work only for fields.
```

before click:
[image: before]
after:
[image: after]

So, i think it's bad idea to hide text, but you can easily hide Textfield, lets do it!

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{Enter name: }


\begin{insDLJS}{mydljs}{ }
    this.getField('testLabel').borderColor=color.transparent;
function hide(){
     if(this.getField("test").display == display.visible){
          this.getField("test").display = display.hidden;
          this.getField("testLabel").display = display.hidden;
     } else{
         this.getField("test").display = display.visible;
         this.getField("testLabel").display = display.visible;
     }
}
\end{insDLJS}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=testLabel,value=Enter name:,width=\mylen,readonly]{} % I don't know why but width=\whidthof and width=\the\whidthof don't work :(
\TextField[name=test]{} \\
\PushButton[onclick={hide();},
]{hide}\\[0.2cm]
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

before: [image]

after: [image]

Another solution of this problem to replace labels with defaultValue, example:

```
\TextField[name=test2,default=Enter something,
onfocus={
if(event.target.value==event.target.defaultValue)event.target.value='';
},
onblur={
if(event.target.value=='')event.target.value=event.target.defaultValue;
}
]{}
```

before click: [image]

after: [image]

You can hide it as before.