# Making text clickable so that when clicked on, the text is copied

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste

I was wondering if there was some way to make it so that when you click on certain text in a latex document, it is immediately copied. I am trying to make an address book for myself and it would be nice if I could just click the email addresses or postal codes instead of having to highlight and copy since it can be quite finicky.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\geometry{vmargin = 1cm, hmargin = 1cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster force size = false, raster columns =3, ,raster column skip = 4mm,
size=small,colframe=Silver,colback=yellow!10!white]
\tcbitem 
\textbf{Example 1}\\
Example1@texmail.com

\vspace{5mm}

1234 Road Pkwy,\\
Moonview, ZZ\\
B4H 4H4
\tcbitem 
\textbf{Example 2}\\
Example2@texmail.com

\vspace{5mm}

4321 RR Rd,\\
Sunview, ZZ\\
B5H 5H5

\tcbitem 
\textbf{Example 3}\\
Example3@texmail.com

\vspace{5mm}

2143 Ave Blvd,\\
Retrograde, UV\\
54321
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can double-click the e-mail address to select it and then press ctrl-c (or right-click and copy), and triple-click the postal code (or the street address for example) to select the whole line. Isn't that an easy way already?

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know about the triple click thing. That works! I also just wanted to see what the limitations of latex are. If this too much for latex, that is fine.

Comment: You can use JavaScript within a PDF to do things like copying to the clipboard, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444917/the-tikz-game-package-a-tex-sx-project/444956 for an example of the general approach, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117141/hide-latex-parts-through-javascript for a more convenient syntax using the `insdljs` package. However, this does not work in all PDF viewers, Adobe Reader is more or less the only reader that supports this fully.